# Clustering algorithm on undefined number of classes

Tags: classification, clustering

Imagine we have a large system of images. We are trying to search for an image and images that are closer to it. One strategy I could think of is to embed the image say into a 100-dimensional vector. Then we can use a clustering algorithm like $k$-means. However, our number of categories can grow as we might have a group of pictures for bikers, pedestrians, cars, bicycles, falcons, etc. That might not be an efficient use of $k$-means. Would you suggest a better machine learning approach than $k$-means, please? The purpose again is to do an image search given that each image is embedded in a 100-dimensional vector. In general, going with clustering algorithms does not feel right as the number of classes could grow as we don't have a predefined number of classes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is "How can I apply clustering when I don't know how many clusters exist in the data?" Is this a fair summary of the problem? Or are you asking something else? There are lots of alternative clustering methods to $k$ means, so an obvious place to start looking would be with something like DBSCAN or spectral clustering, both of which do not require you to know the number of clusters before applying the algorithm.

Comment: @Sycorax. Thank you. Do they scale well with high dimensions, please?

Comment: See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348512/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-spectral-clustering-and-why-is-it-so and https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129545/what-would-be-the-time-complexity-of-dbscan-algorithm

Comment: @Sycorax. Your summary is correct. I just have high-dimensional data. The embeddings are very close for similar images and far for dissimilar ones as I tested this. But the embeddings represent countless number of objects from cars to flowers, ... That is why I need something that scale well

Comment: What do you mean by scaling? Why would changing the number of objects depicted in the images change the time complexity of the algorithm?